# add a line break to dynamic string?

Tags: php

I have some dynamic string get from database . how can i insert a line break to look like this : NOte : i can't edit string

From:

```
From Wednesday, Jul 6, 2016 till Thursday, Jul 7, 2016 (1 night): 1 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra adult) and 1 x Deluxe Room - Twin (2 Adults, 2 Children). Food arrangement: Breakfast
From Saturday, Jul 2, 2016 till Sunday, Jul 3, 2016 (2 nights): 3 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra child) (2 Adults, 2 Children). Food arrangement: Breakfast
```

To:

```
From Wednesday, Jul 6, 2016 till Thursday, Jul 7, 2016 (1 night).
1 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra adult)
1 x Deluxe Room - Twin (2 Adults, 2 Children)
Food arrangement: Breakfast

From Saturday, Jul 2, 2016 till Sunday, Jul 3, 2016 (2 nights).
3 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra child) (2 Adults, 2 Children)
Food arrangement: Breakfast
```

Comment: What logic is there to adding the line breaks? (Added before each room and before food?)

Comment: Yes , and it replace (1 night): -> (1 night).

Comment: How do you build that string in the first place? It might be easier to just add them earlier in the process (like when SELECTing from the db)

Comment: we have to use old record though so i think it's not posible

Comment: and this text from old record

Comment: What's output format? console? HTML? PlainText?

Comment: That stinks. You should definitely try to fix that. There are atleast 9 columns worth of data there and probably multiple tables. Without that, you'll need to use `str_replace` very carefully or even [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) even more carefully

Comment: AndyRyu :it's plaintext
Terminus: yeah i know , it really annoying

Comment: have you try nl2br() http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php . I believe the text came from <textearea> when inserting to database. this nl2br should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str="From Wednesday, Jul 6, 2016 till Thursday, Jul 7, 2016 (1 night): 1 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra adult) and 1 x Deluxe Room - Twin (2 Adults, 2 Children). Food arrangement: Breakfast
From Saturday, Jul 2, 2016 till Sunday, Jul 3, 2016 (2 nights): 3 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra child) (2 Adults, 2 Children). Food arrangement: Breakfast"
;

$output="";
$arr=explode("From", $str);
for ($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++){
$temp=explode(":", $arr[$i]);
$start="From ".$temp[0].".\r\n";
$rm=str_replace("Food arrangement", "", $temp[1]);
$rooms=explode("and", $rm);
$end="Food arrangement: ".$temp[2]."\r\n";
$output.=$start;
foreach ($rooms as $room){
        $output.= $room."\r\n";
}
$output.=$end;
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Base on your code , fix some thing . It work perfectly . Thank you

Comment: @user3064132 glad to be of help =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$str="From Wednesday, Jul 6, 2016 till Thursday, Jul 7, 2016 (1 night): 1 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra adult) and 1 x Deluxe Room - Twin (2 Adults, 2 Children). Food arrangement: Breakfast
From Saturday, Jul 2, 2016 till Sunday, Jul 3, 2016 (2 nights): 3 x Deluxe Room - Double (+ 1 extra child) (2 Adults, 2 Children). Food arrangement: Breakfast"
;

echo $str ."<br><br><br>";
$new_string=str_replace(".",".\n",$str);

echo nl2br($new_string);


?>
```